# como cargar los valores de un formulario desde el $scope al input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Tengo un problema al intentar jalar un dato del $scope e insertarlo como value en input.

Dicho valor se determina desde un select que es parte de mi código del form. El select que determina es "Recurso" y pongo condición de que si es "Municipal" me jale un dato de una función $scope y lo ponga como value en el input para después ese valor se guarde en una base de datos, pero no logro hacer que se dato desde el $scope se refleje en el input.

¿Podrían ayudarme de favor?

**FORM**

```
<form ng-submit="registrar()" >    
    <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
        <label for="ID">ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="IDObra" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <label for="Recurso">Recurso</label>
        <select ng-model="recurso" class="form-control" name="recurso">
            <option ng-value="Municipal" >Municipal</option>
            <option id="dos" ng-value="Estatal">Estatal</option>
            <option id="dos"ng-value="Federal">Federal</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2" >
        <label for="numObra">No. Obra </label>               
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-if="recurso == 'Municipal'" ng-model="numObra" ng-init="value='{{numero}}'"> 
    </div>
```

**controlador AngularJS (Angular 1)**

```
var empleadoControllers = angular.module('empleadoControllers', []);

empleadoControllers.controller('EmpleadoListadoCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    numero();
    empleados();
    profesiones();


    function numero(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8888/base2/api/?a=numero').then(function(r){
            $scope.numero = r.data;            
        });
    }   
    function empleados(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8888/base2/api/?a=listar').then(function(r){
            $scope.model = r.data;
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes leer mas acerca de AngularJS (Angular 1.x), cuando declaras un input con ng-model="ejemplo" el valor del ejemplo se mostrara en el input, es el equivalente a realizar con html lo siguiente

```
<input name="ejemplo" id="ejemplo" value="{{ejemplo}}">
```

para fines practicos para que te funcione debes hacer algo como

```
 $scope.numObra = numero;
```